# mcrypt linux how to use rijndael 256 cbc

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, mcrypt

I am working on linux/ubuntu. I found out that mcrypt is automatically included as a library in this platform. I want to create an encryption with aes 256 and cbc padding 7 (iv). Could someone please give me an example of how to encrypt a string with aes 256 and cbc iv, padding 7?

Rijndael is the same with aes.!

this is the link i've found with the library i would like to use: http://linux.die.net/man/3/mcrypt

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you asking how to use `mcrypt`? Here's a basic skeleton:

```
#include <mcrypt.h>

int main()
{
  char algo[] = "rijndael-256";
  char mode[] = "cbc";

  char key[] = ...
  char iv[]  = ...

  MCRYPT td = mcrypt_module_open(algo, NULL, mode, NULL);
  if (td == MCRYPT_FAILED) { /* error */ }

  int r =  mcrypt_generic_init(td, key, keysize, iv);

  /* use  mdecrypt_generic() or mcrypt_generic() */

  mcrypt_generic_deinit(td);

  mcrypt_module_close(td);
}
```

You have to check the actual key size and IV size with `mcrypt_enc_get_key_size(td)` and `mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size(td)` and provide suitable key and IV data.

---

Edit: Because it's so simple, here's an algorithm to add and strip PCKS7 padding:

```
std::string add_pkcs7_padding(std::string s, std::size_t n)
{
  const std::size_t fill = n - (s.length() % n);
  s.append(fill, static_cast<char>(fill));
  return s;
}

std::string strip_pkcs7_padding(std::string s, std::size_t n)
{
  const std::size_t pad = static_cast<unsigned char>(*s.rbegin());
  return s.substr(0, s.length() - pad);
}
```

(Library-grade code would of course test that `n` can be represented by a `char`, and that during stripping the input string is non-empty and the padding is valid.)

Comment: thx for the example. My IV is [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]. And the key is a 32 key string like: KEY= "AESD-CBED-POKF-OHFB-SNCJ-POLD-OK". Cab you show me how to put this? Plus I need a PKCS7 padding. Will the encrypted result be in the td variable? THX

Comment: PLUS - IS THIS A .C FILE? HOW TO COMPILE IT WITH MCRYPT? WHERE will i find mcrypt.cpp code if i want to compile it statically (no dependencies). THX!! REALLY APPRECIATE:)

Comment: Please just read the manual. mcrypt has a great manual that should answer all this. On Linux, type `man libmcrypt`.

Comment: I don't think mcrypt has any functions for generating padding. You're expected to supply input data at the correct size, i.e. a multiple of the block size. Maybe you can find a padding algorithm somewhere else.

Comment: By the way, your IV needs to have the correct size. Use the function I listed to determine that size.

Comment: what is the strip padding 7 for?

Comment: Thanks for the padding code. In strip_pkcs7_padding() you don't seem to use parameter "n".