# Qt | Can't get any cryptographic library to work

Tags: qt, encryption, shared-libraries

Over a week now I tried to implement every Cryptography-Library I could possibly find into QT to encrypt files and strings, but it just seems to be impossible for me.
I started with a clean Ubuntu-Installation, updated everything, installed QT and as Openssl is allready installed on Ubuntu, I tried to start with that.
I've read some tutorials, tried some examples, but nothing I did seemed to solve my "undefined reference" problem.
I googled for the right libs I maybe had to add to the project file, but nothing worked.
As Openssl didn't work for me, I googled my way through "QCA", "Crypto++", "MCrypt" and some public librarys I found.
With the first three I got the "undefined reference" errors again and the other librarys either had depracted code or wrong conversions between data types in the code itself.

I'm new to the whole cryptographic stuff, but I can't get it to work at all.
It would just be awesome if someone could release me from my pain and help me to get ANY library working from a clean ubuntu installation with QT.
I just have to do something wrong....it can't be that the tutorials I found on the web are working just fine for everbody else.

As an example....I installed the packages "libmcrypt-dev", "libmcrypt4" and "mcrypt" and followed the code example here: [mcrypt linux how to use rijndael 256 cbc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7347713/mcrypt-linux-how-to-use-rijndael-256-cbc)
The include works fine, the header file can be found and the code for the mcrypt classes is highlighted, so it should work, right?
But as I try to compile the code, I get "undefined reference" errors in every line that uses a function from mcrypt.
This also happened with all the other librarys....though I can't find anything missing that others did.
No additional includes are stated anywhere nor any additional library-references which I'd have to include in the project file.

What am I doing wrong?
I fear I don't really have anything to show you guys either, except you want to see a huge list with "undefined reference" errors. :-/

If I try something like that:

```
#include <mcrypt.h>

int main()
{
    MCRYPT td = mcrypt_module_open("rijndael-256", NULL, "cbc", NULL);
    mcrypt_module_close(td);
}
```

I get the following errors

```
error: undefined reference to `mcrypt_module_open'
error: undefined reference to `mcrypt_module_close'
```

Project file:

```
QT       += core

QT       -= gui

TARGET = untitled
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`error: undefined reference` says, that linker can not find library itself. It has headers files, that you have included, but does not see source. To fix this, you have to tell linker, where the sources are, so add in your `*.pro` file add line, for example like this for `libmcrypt` library:

`LIBS += -L/path/to -lmcrypt`

In linux, if you have installed with apt-get install or something similar, -L usually is not needed

Comment: Thanks, that solved it. I also got openssl working now with adding the line: LIBS += -lcrypto